# MVC 5 Could this result in an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, object, constructor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and have a question in regards to a potential coding flaw.

I have an `AccountService` class that has a `MapLocationMarkerService` object that is initialized in the constructor call. The `MapLocationMarkerService` has a constructor parameter that is the `AccountService`.

When I create an `AccountService` object, I am passing in the current `AccountService` object when initializing the `MapLocationMarkerService` object.

Could this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: With dependency injection, yes, this can cause a stack overflow.  You should be defining distinct layers to avoid this.

Comment: A code sample would make this a lot clearer, but as I understand it, you create an `AccountService`, which then creates a `MapLocationMarkerService`, which holds a reference to the parent `AccountService`. Since the `MapLocationMarkerService` doesn't ever try to instantiate a new `AccountService`, I don't see where an infinite loop could occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No:

```
public class A
{
  public B b;

  public A()
  {
    b = new B(this);
  }
}

public class B
{
  public A a;

  public B(A _a)
  {
    a = _a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called *Circular References*. It may indicate that services have not been decoupled properly. You can refactor some of the methods into another service class to remove circular reference.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616344/What-is-Circular-dependency-and-how-do-we-resolve) article may help you understand and resolve the issue.